# TDD Getters and Setters in Scala

Tags: scala, tdd, getter-setter

**Test**

```
package com.utrecht.numbersequences

import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import org.mockito.Mockito._

class NumberSequencesTests extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter with MockitoSugar {
  test("testCity") {
    NumberSequences.city_("utrecht")
    assert("utrecht" === NumberSequences.city())
  }
}
```

**Code**

```
package com.utrecht.numbersequences

import scala.collection.immutable.Stream.consWrapper

object NumberSequences {
  var _city: String = null 

  def city_=(_city:String) = this._city = _city  
  def city = this._city
}
```

**Outcome**

- value not a member of object
- not enough arguments for method apply: (index: Int)Char in class StringOps

  > test
  >   [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\path\to\developme
  >   nt\scalaNumberSequences\target\scala-2.10\test-classes...
  >   [error] C:\path\to\development\scalaNumberSequences\src
  >   \test\scala\com\utrecht\numbersequences\NumberSequencesTest.scala:32: value city
  >   _ is not a member of object com.utrecht.numbersequences.NumberSequences
  >   [error]     NumberSequences.city_("utrecht")
  >   [error]                     ^
  >   [error] C:\path\to\development\scalaNumberSequences\src
  >   \test\scala\com\utrecht\numbersequences\NumberSequencesTest.scala:33: not enough
  >    arguments for method apply: (index: Int)Char in class StringOps.
  >   [error] Unspecified value parameter index.
  >   [error]     assert("utrecht" === NumberSequences.city())
  >   [error]                                              ^
  >   [error] two errors found
  >   [error] (test:compile) Compilation failed
  >   [error] Total time: 1 s, completed Aug 10, 2014 5:52:16 PM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NumberSequences.city_=("utrecht")
//OR
NumberSequences.city = "utrecht"
```

but not:

```
NumberSequences.city_("utrecht") // city_ is not a method existing in the object
```